# Loop to import xml from URL based on cell value and report results to a corresponding cell

Tags: excel, xml, vba, loops

I have a spreadsheet that builds a URL to query an API. The URLs go into column A on a sheet called "CheckURLs".
When the URL is checked, the xml results go into another sheet called "Results" into column D.

I will have around 500 URLs to check, so want to work out how to loop this.

I can't get the 'Destination' part of the code to offset to another cell - and don't know how to split the function.

The code below is a manual loop through three records.
I would like to make this automatic through all records where there is a value in Sheets("CheckURLs") column A.

```vb
Sub Import_Data()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    IIf Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A2") = "", ExitSub, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckURLs").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A2").Value, ImportMap:= _
      Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("D2")
    
    IIf Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A3") = "", ExitSub, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckURLs").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A3").Value, ImportMap:= _
      Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("D3")
    
    IIf Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A4") = "", ExitSub, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckURLs").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=Sheets("CheckURLs").Range("A4").Value, ImportMap:= _
      Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("D4")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the missing pieces would be the [Worksheet.Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) property. This lets you specify a cell using numbers for the row and column, like this way of specifying cell A2:

```
Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(2, 1)
```

If we then use a variable for the row part, then we can see how we could loop things:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = 2

IIf Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(lngRow, 1) = ""...
lngRow = lngRow + 1
IIf Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(lngRow, 1) = ""...
lngRow = lngRow + 1
```

If we then extract the condition from the `IIf` calls into a `Do...Until` loop with the check at the start and we also specify that we are looking at the `Value` of this cell:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = 2

Do Until Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = ""
    ' do stuff
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
```

We no longer need the `IIf` statements or the "ExitSub" parts or the `Activate` parts. This gives us:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = 2

Do Until Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = ""
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=Sheets("CheckURLs").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value, ImportMap:= _
        Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Results").Cells(lngRow, 4)
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
```

We can still make things better by looking at how we are specifying the worksheets we are working with. Because we have two separate places where we refer to `Sheets("CheckURLs")` that opens up the potential that any future changes could update one reference but not the other.

If instead we create variables for each worksheet then we only need to specify the actual worksheet once. This makes it easier to change in future. We can also specify that these worksheets are in the same workbook as the code (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`) and we can specify that they are Worksheets rather than any other kind of sheet. Note that we need to use [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) here because they are object variables. This gives us:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = 2

Dim wsCheck As Worksheet
Set wsCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CheckURLs")

Dim wsResult As Worksheet
Set wsResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

Do Until wsCheck.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = ""
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=wsCheck.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value, ImportMap:= _
        Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=wsResult.Cells(lngRow, 4)
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much - works like a dream. Great to have all the steps laid out as well - thanks for the additional effort, really useful.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer using the checkmark